# Is it posible to sync latest state in function

Tags: reactjs

Here is the Code .

When I click the "Test" button, it will trigger `SetText` to update the number.
And then I click the "Stop" button. I hope it will display `console.log("STOP")`.
But it seems like I can't get the latest `isStop` value in the `for...of` loop when `isStop` change.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isStop, SetIsStop] = useState(false);
  const [text, SetText] = useState(false);
  function delay() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={async () => {
          for (let item of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) {
            if (isStop) {
              console.log("STOP");
            } else {
              SetText(item);
              console.log(isStop);
              await delay();
            }
          }
        }}
      >
        Test
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => SetIsStop(true)}>Stop</button>
      <div>{text}</div>
      <div>isStop: {isStop ? "STOP" : "NOT STOP"}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is it posible to sync latest state in function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To you quesiton, `Is it posible to sync latest state in function ?`, the answer is YES!
You can have your own `global` or `shared` state object out of `App` instead of the state variable from a closure. Set a breakpoint to inspect closures your code has and see the variables inside. See the runnable code [https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-wilbur-pouh4][1] or code below and compare to your code.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";


import { useState } from "react";

class State {
  constructor() {
    this.stop = false;
  }
}
const myState = new State(); // KEY POINT!

export default function App() {
  const [isStop, SetIsStop] = useState(false);
  const [text, SetText] = useState(false);
  function delay() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  const changeState = () => {
    myState.stop = !myState.stop;
    SetIsStop(myState.stop);
  };

  const asyncFunc = async context => {
    for (let item of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) {
      if (myState.stop) {
        console.log("STOP");
      } else {
        SetText(item);
        console.log(isStop);
      }
      await delay();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={asyncFunc}>Test</button>
      <button onClick={changeState}>Stop</button>
      <div>{text}</div>
      <div>isStop: {myState.stop ? "STOP" : "NOT STOP"}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The reason why your code does not work is when `onClick` is triggered, a closure which contains `isStop` is created for executing the callback of onClick event. It does not matter how the outer logic changes `isStop`, the value of `isStop` in that closure doesn't change.

By the way, if you was particularly going to do a thing periodically, `setInterval` should be way more readable and flexible than what you have.

Comment: Very interesting! So how would you go about doing this?

Comment: Well, this is what a debugger can tell if you refuse to learn from books, right?